# Always getting java.io.FileNotFoundException and requiring 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' when querying Hive and transforming data

Tags: apache-spark

I run a scheduled process which queries a table in Hive using sparkSQL and does some transformations and then counting the rows in the dataset:

```
val dataset       = this.query_hive(sql_statement)
val result_interm = this.transformation_step1(dataset)
val result        = this.transformation_step2(result_interm)
println(result.count())
```

The issue I have is the table in Hive, which gets updated rather frequently, and whenever its getting updated while the spark job is running, I get `Spark java.io.FileNotFoundException, invalidate the cache in Spark by running REFRESH TABLE table` error message from Spark. My question: is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try following options:

1. Run `REFRESH TABLE` right before using some transformations.
2. Write some `try-finally` code section where you will emulate some kind of retry logic.
3. Actually, third option I was not able to test, but you could try to create the table that updates frequently as `MANAGED` table and then create another `EXTERNAL` table which will point to location with the `MANAGED` table, in this way it could read the old values and do not crush on `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Hope this could help.